Is type punning with a union undefined behavior in a mixed C/C++ environment?
As previously discussed here and here, type punning with a union is explicitly allowed in the C11 standard, but is not allowed in C++.
How does this come into play in an environment where C and C++ code is mixed?  A trivial example where this might happen:
c_code.c:
#include "c_code.h"

// Does where this is declared matter?
union UnionTest test;

int read_int_in_c(void)
{
    return test.m_int;
}

void write_int_in_c(void)
{
    test.m_int = 3;
}

float read_float_in_c(void)
{
    return test.m_float;
}

void write_float_in_c(void)
{
    test.m_float = 3.14f;
}

c_code.h:
#ifndef C_CODE_H
#define C_CODE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

union UnionTest
{
    int m_int;
    float m_float;
};

extern union UnionTest test;

int read_int_in_c(void);
void write_int_in_c(void);
float read_float_in_c(void);
void write_float_in_c(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* C_CODE_H */

cpp_code.h
#ifndef CPP_CODE_H
#define CPP_CODE_H

#include "c_code.h"

int read_int_in_cpp(void);
void write_int_in_cpp(void);
float read_float_in_cpp(void);
void write_float_in_cpp(void);

#endif /* CPP_CODE_H */

cpp_code.cpp:
#include "cpp_code.h"

// Does where this is declared matter?
//UnionTest test;

int read_int_in_cpp(void)
{
    return test.m_int;
}

void write_int_in_cpp(void)
{
    test.m_int = 3;
}

float read_float_in_cpp(void)
{
    return test.m_float;
}

void write_float_in_cpp(void)
{
    test.m_float = 3.14f;
}

main.cpp:
#include "c_code.h"
#include "cpp_code.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // Case 1:
    write_int_in_c();
    float test1 = read_float_in_cpp();
    std::cout << "The value of test1 is now " << test1 << std::endl;
    // Case 3:
    write_int_in_cpp();
    float test2 = read_float_in_c();
    std::cout << "The value of test2 is now " << test2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

The code is compiled with
cc -Wall -c c_code.c -o c_code.o
c++ -Wall -c cpp_code.cpp -o cpp_code.o
c++ -Wall main.cpp c_code.o cpp_code.o -o exe
Let's consider the following cases:

An instance of a union is declared in a .c file (either statically declared and resolved via extern and the linker, or a pointer is passed to C++ code).  The m_int member is written to via the C function write_int_in_c() and the m_float member is read via the C++ function read_float_in_cpp().

Same as above, but the instance is now declared in a .cpp file and passed to C code.  Does this make a difference?

An instance of a union is declared in a .c file (either statically declared and resolved via extern and the linker, or a pointer is passed to C++ code).  The m_int member is written to via the C++ function write_int_in_cpp() and the m_float member is read via the C function read_float_in_c().

Same as above, but the instance is now declared in a .cpp file and passed to C code.  Does this make a difference?


I am curious as to what guarantees the standards make (if any) in the above cases, as well as behavior seen by common compilers.

The C and C++ standards define nothing about calling from one language to another. (C++ specifies some things for C language linkage but nothing about calling routines in C.) When you call from C to C++ or Fortran or Swift or assembly language or any other language, the C standard does not define the behavior. When you call from C++ to C or Fortran or Swift or assembly language or any other language, the C standard does not define the behavior.

What you can do is reason that, if modules are compiled separately, and there is no cross-module communication other than through the passing of arguments and return values as specified in an ABI and the various types have corresponding meanings, then a C module must behave as if another C module had passed it the data, and a C++ module must behave as if another C++ module had passed it the data, by virtue of the fact that a separately compiled module must work according to its standard when linked with another module in the same language.

@EricPostpischil This may however be a bit more tricky if something like LTO is used across C and C++ translation units in which case the optimizer might operate on both at the same time.

Note that in C or C++ the sizes of fundamental types is weakly specified.  For example, int can be anything 16 bits and up. I don't think float has a specified size though I've never seen anything but 32 bits. Punning a 32 bit float from a 16 bit int could have very interesting results.

@user4581301 That's a good point.  Maybe we can consider the case where sizeof(int) == sizeof(float) (or modify the question to use uint32_t instead) and also consider the case sizeof(int) != sizeof(float).  I'd assume that writing a 16-bit int and later trying to read a 32-bit float would not be well-defined, since the last 16-bits aren't initialized.

_Static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(float), "mismatch in sizes of int and float");

On the C++ side use std::bit_cast from C++20 <bits>. If bit_cast doesn't fail at compile time, the result is a reliable punned value. On C side, refer to C standard or platform docs.
